# Gulp src glob : multiple files patterns not matching

Tags: gulp, glob

I am creating a build script for a Node app.

I had created a Powershell (PSake) script, but now I need to port it to Gulp because I need to run it on Mac.

Basically, I copy the sources somewhere and clean them up (remove all unnecessary files like readme & stuff) to create a package that will be installed on client PCs, so I want to keep the file number as small as possible.

In one place, my Powershell looks like this :

```
Get-ChildItem "$srcout\node_modules\" -Recurse | ? {
    $_.FullName -match "\\\.bin\\" `
        -or $_.Name -match "[\w]+\.md$" `
        -or $_.Name -match "licen[c|s]e" `
        -or $_.Name -match "authors" `
        -or $_.Name -match "bower.json" `
        -or $_.Name -match "gruntfile\.js" `
        -or $_.Name -match "makefile" `
        -or $_.Name -match "cakefile"
    } | % {
        Remove-Item "$($_.FullName)" -Force -Recurse
    }
```

So far I have written this for Gulp :

```
var pump = require('pump');
var through = require('through2');

    pump([
        gulp.src([
            '**/node_modules/**/.bin/',
            '**/node_modules/**/*.md',
            '**/node_modules/**/licen+(s|c)e*',
            '**/node_modules/**/author*',
            '**/node_modules/**/bower.json',
            '**/node_modules/**/gruntfile.js',
            '**/node_modules/**/makefile',
            '**/node_modules/**/cakefile'
        ], { 
            cwd: srcout,
            nocase: true
        }),
        through.obj(function(f, e, cb) {

            if (fs.statSync(f.path).isFile()) {
                fs.unlinkSync(f.path);
            } else {
                rmdir.sync(f.path);
            }

            cb(null, f);
        })
    ],
    done);
```

The `/.bin/` and `*.md` globs are working fine, but the rest do not find anything...

What am I missing or doing wrong ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replaced the glob by a [fs-extra](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra) `walk` call, but it doesn't really answer why the glob does not work.

```
var fs = require('fs-extra');

gulp.task('cleanupapp', [ 'build' ], function(done) {
    fs.walk(path.join(srcout, 'node_modules'))
    .on('data', function (item) {

        // normalize folder paths (win/mac)
        var f = item.path.replace('/', '\\');

        if (f.match(/\\.bin\\/i) ||
            f.match(/\.md$/i) ||
            f.match(/licen[c|s]e/i) ||
            f.match(/author[s]?/i) ||
            f.match(/bower\.json$/i) ||
            f.match(/gruntfile\.js$/i) ||
            f.match(/makefile$/i) ||
            f.match(/cakefile$/i)) {

            if (fs.accessSync(f, fs.W_OK)) {
                fs.removeSync(f);
            }
        }
    })
    .on('end', function () {
        done();
    });
});
```